# How to create a ssh tunnel chain in one command?

Tags: ssh, tunnel

We have a serverA to connect to.  Then we use serverA to connect to databaseB. Setup like this in Putty (windows):

**Session1:**
1. connect to admin@serverA
2. setup tunnel local port 10022 to databaseB:22
3. run 'vi'

**Session2:**
1. connect to admin@localhost:10022
2. setup tunnel local port 1521 to database 1521
3. run 'vi'

(vi is used to hold session)

Then program use localhost:1521 for database connection.

I wonder if I can do it in a single command or a batch file in cygwin?
Note that I cannot open port on serverA

Answer (score 11):

```
ssh -L 1521:127.0.0.1:61521 admin@serverA ssh -L 61521:127.0.0.1:1521 admin@databaseB
```

or using plink (Putty link) from a command window:

```
plink -ssh -L 1521:127.0.0.1:61521 admin@serverA ssh -L 61521:127.0.0.1:1521 admin@databaseB
```

Answer (score 4):

As to running this as a single command, the previous answer is correct but if the second ssh requires a password, it will probably not work (depending on ssh default configuration).  You will have to force the allocation of a pseudo-tty by using the -t option, as in:

```
ssh -t -L 1521:127.0.0.1:61521 admin@serverA ssh -L 61521:127.0.0.1:1521 admin@databaseB
```

(this works using cygwin's ssh command)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ProxyCommand option for that. Put the following into your ssh configuration file (which is usually at `~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host direct-serverB
ProxyCommand ssh admin@serverA ssh admin@serverB sshd -i
```

Then you can connect to the serverB as if it was directly available:

```
% ssh -L 1521:localhost:1521 admin@direct-serverB
```

This command *does not open* any ports on the intermediate serverA. However, it has a drawback that you need to authenticate to serverB both from serverA and from your local machine.

If the serverA has `netcat` installed, then you could write this into your ssh config:

```
Host direct-serverB
ProxyCommand ssh admin@serverA nc -q0 serverB 22
```

and drop the serverA→serverB authentication step.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try running:

```
ssh admin@serverA -L 10022:databaseB:22
ssh admin@localhost -p 10022 -L 1521:database2:1521
```

But man, I cringe even suggesting it. The people who firewalled off DatabaseB probably had a good reason for doing so. Talk with them.

Comment: In the first command instead of 22, if we give 1521 then directly connecting 10022 will not take to db?

Comment: @Nasir, excellent question; I recreated what the original question was doing, but perhaps there's a better way to solve the problem. This approach might be required if the database server only listens on `localhost` IP addresses, or if the authentication for the user in question requires connections to come from `localhost` IP addresses. But you're right, if the database is set up more permissively, avoiding the second ssh would be more reliable and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what worked for me.
-- My goal was to point the client application to localhost:1115 and have it actually be connecting to target_db_server:1433.
-- target_db_server is only accessible from jumpserver2.
-- jumpserver2 is only accessible from jumpserver1.
-- The command therefore connects to jumpserver1, prompts for a token (in my case), then connects to jumpserver2 and asks for the password for that server then the local client can make the connection.

```
ssh -L 1115:127.0.0.1:1115 username@jumpserver1 -tt ssh -L 1115:target_db_server:1433  username@jumpserver2
```

I found that the connection would time out, which was not ideal.  The following fixed that:

```
echo "Host *" >> ~/.ssh/config
echo "ServerAliveInterval 60" >> ~/.ssh/config
```